# What happens if you don't pay the Panamá exit tax?

Tags: central-america, passport-stamps, panama, taxes

Yesterday we landed after a trip from Panama to Spain departing from PTY airport. Today a friend that travelled to Panama 3 years ago has told me that he had to pay a 40 dollars tax when he leaved the airport. Also he said that he has an exit stamp in his passport. Of course, I've checked this with Mr. Google and I've found [some sites](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294480-i1194-k4134285-Entry_and_exit_costs-Panama_City_Panama_Province.html) that reports about this $40 tax.

I have no exit stamp from Panama and I haven't paid any tax when leaved. I assume that this is not going to have any consequences unless I try to enter again in Panama, but if I try to go into Panama again, will I have any problem? Is still this tax in effect? Do I need an exit stamp?

Comment: Not sure about exit tax by that name, but nowadays, airport tax, fuel surcharge and whatnot are included in the ticket price when you buy it.

Comment: @AyeshK Exit tax is something that some countries impose, separately to airport tax. Sometimes it is in the ticket, sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The $40 Airport Departure Tax is already included in most air tickets.

Years ago, each traveler paid the tax to a designated tax collector at the airport and got a stamp or ticket signifying they had paid the tax. This was actually pretty common at airports all over the world, but now most airlines collect the tax as part of the ticket price, then forward the money to the appropriate government.

If you can find the full fare breakdown for your ticket, you will likely see a number of different departure taxes and passenger service charges from governments and airports along your route.

Comment: This is correct, though I'd add that some countries/airports still have the tax collector at the airport to collect the exit fee. This is the case in the Philippines (at least when leaving from Cebu,) for instance.

Comment: I was surprised by such an exit tax in Bali, right after I had gotten rid of the last of local currency. Unusually, they were unwilling to accept anything but (local) cash, which forced me (and many others) to walk back completely out of the airport to a working ATM (with high withdrawal fees) ...

Comment: Most countries have such taxes, so it behooves the traveler to research that aspect to be prepared.  Travel agents used to tell their clients, but now with online everything the traveler bears 100% responsibility.